# How long should a battery take to recharge from a wall socket charger?

Tags: battery, battery-charger

My battery died and I suspect the alternator. To test I need to get the car running again and so borrowed a wall socket charger.

I have no idea how long I need to let the battery charge for.

Would anyone know how long I need to wait?

Comment: What is the amp/hour rating of the charger and the battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long does it take to charge a battery?  Ideally assuming 100% percent efficiency a 10 A battery charger would charge a 50 A/h (Ampere/hour) battery in about 5 hours.

Hours of charge =  Ampere-Hour rating/charge rate  ....ideally

In reality due the fact that when a battery is charging the  charge rate is not constant. As a battery over time becomes charged the charging rate decreases. In reality it ends up being about twice the ideal calculated value.

Using the values used in the example above...10 hours would be expected.

Answer (score 0):

If the battery is okay, you might need an hour to make it turn the starter and start a car. The rest should  be done by alternator IF IT WORKS.